# Lost my BTC, though my wallet is still available

Tags: bitcoin-core

Recently I have reinstalled Bitcoin qt because my HDD crashed. Fortunately I had a backup of my wallet.dat, but there is still one problem.

After the installation I replaced the wallet.dat with my old wallet.dat. If I start Bitcoin qt now, I can not see any money in my wallet?!

What can I do now?

Comment: Have you tried running `bitcoin-qt -rescan`?

Comment: Yes, also tried this. It didn't work.

Comment: Do any transactions show at all?  If not, you probably didn't have a good backup.

Comment: How recent was your backup?   Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind uses a keypool, and thus you need to make new backups after a certain number of transactions.

Comment: I even can't see any transactions listed in my client. Bitcoin-qt looks like if I have started it the first time. I am sure the backup includes the latest transactions, I just created it some days before the crash happened.

Answer (score 2):

Are you also sure that you've let Bitcoin qt fully synchronise with the network? Very recently I moved across my wallet.dat to a new installation with no issues.

Comment: I am 100 percent sure, I really don't know what's the problem. It's a pity that I have lost my Bitcoins now.

Comment: I'm quite unsure then. Why don't you enable debugging and take a look at debug.log. Maybe it'll tell you where it's going wrong and if it's failing to load wallet.dat.

Answer (score 2):

Check your wallet address against blockchain.info. verify there are no erroneous transactions / that your using theright wallet.dat file